# phpExcel read long number from cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a problem when reading value from Excel sheet.

This is my code:

```
        $phpExcelObjReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($posFile);
        $phpExcelObj = $phpExcelObjReader->load($posFile);
        foreach ($phpExcelObj->getSheetNames() as $sheetIndex => $sheetName) {
            foreach($phpExcelObj->getSheet($sheetIndex)->getRowIterator() as $row){
                $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
                $cells = array();
                foreach($cellIterator as $cell){
                    $cells[] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
                }
                $fileData[] = $cells;
                //log_message('ERROR', print_r($cells, TRUE));
            }
        }
```

When I read n excel cell having value **358100000**, it is getting stored to DB as **3.581E+8**

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: use bigint in your database..

Comment: Shows how much I know... <sigh> I'll just let PHPExcel get blamed again.... I'm on a real downer today :(

Comment: @MarkBaker Indeed :-P Luckily `(int) floatval($str);` can make sense of that. I really don't know why `intval()` doesn't understand scientific notation for integers that are within bounds but what are you going to do.

Comment: @OP in case you didn't catch that: `$cells[] = (int) floatval($cell->getCalculatedValue());` will fix the problem, ugly as it is. You may want to remove the `(int)` cast if your Excel file may contain numbers that are outside the range of a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: it is not the problem when saving to DB, the getCalculatedValue() itself is returning 3.581E+8. I tried to log the values.

Answer (score 1):

This post really helped me

just add

```
ini_set("precision", "15");
```

set the precision to the number count you need to get, for me its 15 instead of 14 on my php.ini

[Problem reading numbers from excel with PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753469/problem-reading-numbers-from-excel-with-phpexcel/10651335#10651335?newreg=52cf2bb4607f41e0aae7c470727b59a3)