# php excel reader reading numbers incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to read and xlsx file to bulk import to a mysql database.

I can successfully read text fields but when it comes to numbers with large decimal points, it is giving wrong results.

I am using nuovo / spreadsheetreader from github

[SpreadsheetReader.php](https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader/blob/master/SpreadsheetReader.php)
[SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php](https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader/blob/master/SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php)

index.php

```
$Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($orgFilename);

$count = count($Reader);

foreach ($Reader as $Row)
{
    echo $Row[0] . '<br>';
}
```

**Here is my excel data**

690835388.737296
-553772409.572704
16983999.9999999
16983999.9999999
-904762663.342704
0.439514518724299
89055169.9716966
171930071.634401
35291999.9999995 
1151681063.10099

**The output is**

690835388.7373
-553772409.5727
16984000
16984000
-904762663.3427
0.4395145187243
89055169.971697
171930071.6344
35291999.999999
1151681063.101

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Is it rounding up your excel sheet values.?

Comment: ya, but it is rounding different for different values. You can check my excel data and output above. I want the exact number from the excel data with all the decimals

Comment: May be you can raise an issue here. https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader/issues so that the author can solve your problem.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753469/problem-reading-numbers-from-excel-with-phpexcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you stumbled into has nothing to do with the SpreadsheetReader. It's purely based on different precision of floating point numbers in excel and php.

Whent I take one of the numbers from your example and simply do:

```
echo 1151681063.10099;
```

Then the output will be `1151681063.101`.

Every software uses a certain amount of memory for number representation. Some of this memory is used to represent the integer part of the number and some amount is used to represent the fraction part.

For integers it's easy. Every decimal integer can be represented as a binary number which is what computers do. They do arithmetics with numbers which are the sum of multiples of powers of 2.

So for example the number 14 can be expressed as 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 = 8 + 4 + 2 = 14. This works for each and every integer number as long as you have enough memory to store it.

For decimals it's a whole different story. We humans do floating point calculations on the basis of fractions of 10. For example 0.25 = 0.2 + 0.05 = 10^-1 * 2 + 10^-2 * 5. So floating point numbers are set up by adding multiples of 1/10, 1/100, 1/1000...

Computers on the other hand have to represent those numbers as sums of 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16...

For the above example of 0.25 this is easy as we can say it's equivalent to 1/4 which has a clean representation as a binary number (2^-2).

Unfortunately things do not work so smooth for other numbers. If we try to convert 0.3 to a binary number we'll get into trouble. This number has no precise binary representation as we can not write it as the sum of different  2^-N terms.

Computers try to counter this problem by finding a representation which is close most of the time even very close to the real number. How good those representations are depends strongly on the number of bits you use to store floating point numbers. The more memory you invest the better the representation will be.

In your case excel simply uses more memory to store the fraction part of numbers compared to your php interpreter. This results in some kind of deviation when you import those numbers from excel to php.

Edit:

A simple example for this problem is the representation of the fraction 1/3 as a decimal number. As you probably know there is no precise representation and many people will just write 0.3333333.... and add just as many 3's as they need. If we would want to write this number in a number system based on the number 3 than things would become very easy as we would simply write 3^-1.

Edit 2:
Maybe you could try to import those big numbers as strings which can have an arbitrary length in php. This could help if you are just using php to import the data and want to store those data e.g. wihtin a database which may have a completely different precision.

Edit 3:
The precision of numbers is configured via php ini and can be set, see http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision

Edit 4: If you want to dig deeper into the topic of floating point precision then this is a very good article to start with: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html